# Select file button is not opening the files library in webView of iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uiwebview, wkwebview

I have select file button in website which is opening in webview in my iOS application but the button is not opening the files library of iOS device. but the same link is working fine for android and even in desktop browser

I just used the webView simply and tried some delegate methods to listen the click but I am not able to found any method to work in this situation.

```
    if let myUrl: URL = URL(string: urlWeb){
                        webViewTerms.delegate = self
            webViewTerms.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: myUrl))
        }
```

Comment: why using webview for this task? there are many tutorial on how to upload files in swift...

Comment: it's the functionality where user is surfing a kind of website in the iOS application and in that website the user have to select file in the iOS device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have the below code in your website to listen the click event.
Adding a href to your button event

```
"window.location.href = “ myapp://click”;"
```

then below code will work for you.

```
 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    
    if((webView.url?.scheme == "myapp") && webView.url?.host == "click"){
        print("user click the button")
     // Write the code to open Files folder of device.
    }
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.allow)
    
}
```

I hope this would work for you.

Comment: This is the issue from the backend I think,  the button not even returning the event, Not a problem the backend team accepted my request now they are working on it.
Thank You @Krunal